# How do I get items from CosmosDB where the document property is lowercase, but the model property is uppercase?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have a document in my cosmos database called Users with a partition key of "email". I'm retrieving the cosmos data through an Azure function using the GetItemLinqQueryable() function. The type T is of type UserData as shown below:

```
public class UserData
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool isAdmin { get; set; }
    }
```

My cosmos db container is called "users" and has a schema like below:

```
{
    "id": "2",
    "email": "ckelly@gmail.com",
    "isAdmin": false
}
```

I'm calling GetItemLinqQueryable, but it is unable to retrieve values because of the difference in casing between the document properties and the UserData properties. Is there a way I can do the mapping where it's case insensitive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use a model like this?

```
    public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "isComplete")]
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
}
```

Need to add this using as well.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```